# Django - TypeError: unhashable type: 'SQLDecodeErrorDjango '

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I had everything running perfectly but I had to reinstall windows and when I tried to run the code again, it started giving me errors on user registration.
I followed Vitor Freitas guide to make implement multiple user types but only differed in views as he was using class based views and I had no idea what those were at that time.

I have narrowed down the problem where I am creating User table
(This line: `user = User.objects.create(user=account)` in forms.py).

**Models.py**

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self , email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


def create_superuser(self, email, first_name,last_name, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)
    first_name              = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name               = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_user                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Manager              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    file_path = 'resume/{user_id}/{filename}'.format(
                user_id=str(instance.user.id), filename=filename)
    return file_pathenter code here

class User(models.Model):
user                    = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
city                    = models.CharField(max_length=40)
CV                      = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])])
dream_Job_Title         = models.CharField(max_length=200)
industries              = models.CharField(max_length=150)
speciality              = models.CharField(max_length=200)
current_Profession      = models.CharField(max_length=50)
target_Job_Title        = models.CharField(max_length=100)   
feedback                = models.CharField(max_length=200)
rating                  = models.IntegerField()
phone                   = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
university              = models.CharField(max_length=70,default="")
GPA                     = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
Major                   = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
Minor                   = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
Certification           = JSONField()
Accomplishment          = JSONField()
WorkExperience          = JSONField()
Skills                  = JSONField()


REQUIRED_FIELDS=['CV','dream_Job_Title','industries','speciality']



# Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegister(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text='Enter a valid Email')
city  = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email', 'city', 'password1','password2']

@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    account = super().save(commit=False)
    account.is_user = True
    account.save()
    user = User.objects.create(user=account)
    #user.city.add(form.cleaned_data.get('city'))
    user.city = self.cleaned_data.get('city')
    user.save()
    return account

def clean_email(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
```

**views.py**

```
def UserRegister_view(request):
context = {}

user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated and user.is_user: 
    return redirect("UserDashboard")

if request.POST:
    form = UserRegister(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        context['registration_form'] = form
else:
    form = UserRegister()
    context['registration_form'] = form
return render(request, 'UserRegister.html', context)
```

I have also tried upgrading/downgrading dependencies.